# Android Synchronization with AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, synchronization

This is my main activity:

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.add(text);          
        new DoSomethingWithListViewChild(lv, index).execute();
    }
```

And this is the AsyncTask DoSomethingWithListViewChild:

```
public class DoSomethingWithListViewChild extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    TextView tv;

    public DoSomethingWithListViewChild (ListView lv, int index) {
        View v = lv.getChildAt(index - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do something with TV
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that `lv` is still empty when the code `View v = lv.getChildAt(index - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());` is being executed.

I tried some synchronization with lock objects but I'm ending with deadlocks or other errors.

How do I wait untill `lv` is not empty?

**Edit:**

Ok, I tried this:

```
    ...
    ConditionVariable lock = new ConditionVariable(false);
    ...
    public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter.add(text);
                lock.block();
                new DoSomethingWithListViewChild(lv, index).execute();
            }
```

And in my custom adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpannableString> {
    ConditionVariable lock;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout_resource_id, ConditionVariable lock) {
        ...
        this.lock = lock;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        lock.open();
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But the programm just hangs. I need to find the exact moment when `lv` is populated to open the lock. It clearly not in the `getView` method.. It even don't reach the `lock.open();`

Comment: You cannot do modifications to Views from doInBackground(), do your processing in it and then perform modifications on the views in onPostExecute

Comment: I know that... That is not relevant to the question

Comment: did you try only lv.getChildAt(index); ?

Comment: I just did with lv.getChildAt(0) with the same results. This is an obvious threading synchronization problem. Just need to figure it out how to wait until lv is populated before the new AsyncTask thread is trying to access it.

Comment: @Igor so what does // Do something with TV mean ?!!

Comment: I'm sorry @Mohamed_AbdAllah for putting that extremely confusing line. But as the post suggests, the problem occurs much before we even reach this line.

Answer (score 0):

May be needs to call `adapter.notifyDayaSetChanged()` after `adapter.add(text)`